# Ansible use of int filter for comparison

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to compare a variable passed to an Ansible playbook to a numeric value. The expression

```yaml
"{{params.wait_seconds | int > 0 | ternary('yes', 'no')}}"
```

produces the following exception

> ```json
> {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{params.wait_seconds | int > 0 | ternary('yes', 'no')}}): '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"}
> ```

I debug the value for `params.wait_seconds` just prior to the task that produces this error and the value is as follows:

```json
"params": {
  "wait_seconds": "150"
}
```

I am using Ansible 2.10.5 with Python 3.8.5

After several hours of searching for an answer, all explanations indicate this should work. I have not come across any outstanding bug reports saying this does not work. Any constructive suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you would just lose the quotation marks around the 150?

Comment: The parameter value is being provided from outside the playbook and may be a string value of an integer. In this case it is being transferred from a parameter block that does have it without quotation marks. It is a passed in as wait_seconds: "{{passed.wait_seconds}}" which results in it being quoted.

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
  "{{ params.wait_seconds|int > 0|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"
```

The pipe `|` has precedence over comparison `>`. `0` was evaluated as Boolean and piped to `ternary`. The **integer**, `params.wait_seconds|int` was converted to, is compared to the **string**, the result of ternary. This is the reason for the error

> '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

The solution is simple. Close the comparison in parenthesis

```yaml
  "{{ (params.wait_seconds|int > 0)|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"
```

Omitting spaces around pipes improves readability in this case, I think.